# Wait for kafkaTemplate pending future

Tags: java, apache-kafka, future, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am performing an asynchronous operation which returns a future object in a loop (say 10 messages) .
As I understand callback method is automatically triggered and executed when the Future completes its task.

Suppose my 7th future is in pending stage.How can i complete this future exceptionally?

And what is the best way to handle this kind of scenario.

```
List<ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>> cf = new ArrayList<ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>>();

future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);
cf.add(future);

i++;

future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
        syso("sent success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println(" sending failed");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?

If there is an exception, the kafka-clients will call the template's callback with the exception and the template will complete the future exceptionally.

If you really need to do it for some reason (but I'd like to understand why) you can cast it to a `SettableListenerFuture`.

Comment: My point is suppose i am send 10 messages and for some reason 7th future is in pending state then what will happen to my application?Will it keep  waiting for 7th future completion indefinitely ?And is this even a possible scenario?

Comment: It shouldn't happen, but it might (I don't know enough about the `kafka-clients`) but you can iterate over the futures and use `future.get(10, TimUnit.SECONDS)` which will time out if the future is not completed (successfully, or exceptionally) within that time; I would never recommend using `get()` without a timeout on **any** future. If you don't call any get at all then the application won't wait at all.

Comment: The reason i want to do it is because i want to send email when the message processing is done

Comment: So `get(...)` with a timeout is probably the best solution for you.